# MapReduce Common friends pseudocode

Tags: mapreduce, pseudocode

I am currently trying to develop some MapReduce pseudocode for calculating the number of friends in common each user of a particular site has. However, friendships are not mutual and therein lies my problem.
My input consists of a list of users and their respective friends in the form:
A -> (B C E), B -> (C F H) and so on.

The pseudocode I have developed so far is

```
MAP (String Input_key, String Input_Value):
\\ Input_key: person
\\ Input_Value: list of their friends
for each pair in Input_Value:
Emit (pair, 1)

REDUCE (String Intermediate_key, Iterator (Intermediate_Values):
\\ Intermediate_key: pair of friends
\\ Intermediate_values: list of '1's corresponding to the number of people who are friends with both in the pair
int count = 0;
for each v value in Intermediate_values:
count += ParseInt (v);
Emit (Intermediate_key, count);
```

However, I do not think the above code is suitable for the situation where friendships are not mutual (just because A is friends with the pair B and C does not mean that B and C are friends with A).

Can anybody shed some light on this or point me in the right direction to solve this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.